# What causes the voltage potential in a chemistry battery

Tags: electrochemistry

Consider a simple chemistry battery: Zn and Cu with H2SO4 as the electrolyte. The electron will travel from Zn to Cu. And at the Cu side, H ion will get electron and turns to H2. If the circuit is open, Zn itself will react with the acid, and H2 will be generated at the Zn side.
Why there is voltage potential when the circuit is closed? The voltage force the electron to travel around the circuit.

Comment: Your hypothetical cell is just zinc and copper in a beaker with sulfuric acid and no salt bridge. So the zinc reacts with the sulfuric acid. Now look up the Daniell cell, which is discussed in many places, including here. The idea is to *not* just waste the reaction’s free energy as heat. Instead, electrical energy is desired.

Comment: You can benefit greatly by getting this and working through it: K. Schmidt-Rohr, "How Batteries Store and Release Energy: Explaining Basic Electrochemistry", J. Chem. Ed., 95 (10) (2018) 1801-1810. The Zn and Cu Daniell cell is addressed in great detail. TL; DR Cohesive energy differences are the major factor in explaining the behavior of this famous galvanic cell.

Comment: Electrodes can be considered as chemically powered electron pumps, due different tendency of metals performing reaction $\ce{M(s) <=> n e-(s) + M^\mathrm{n+}(aq)}$

Comment: Ed V, Thank you for the info. I just have a quick look at the Daniel cell. In that cell, it seems there is no reaction when the circuit is open, right?

Comment: Open circuit, the Daniell cell (note spelling of Daniell) just slowly dies the diffusion death: some copper ions get into the zinc electrode’s solution reservoir and oxidize the zinc electrode. If the cell was always open circuited, the solutions in the electrode reserviors and salt bridge would all become the same, in the limit, except that copper ions would oxidize zinc metal until one was exhausted. So all the free energy would be wasted as slow heat release.

Comment: By the way, the scenario you describe is basically the lemon ‘battery’, with dilute sulfuric acid in a beaker instead of citric acid in a squishy (to rupture membranes) lemon. So it would work, like the lemon cell, but not well: it is internally *partially* shorted out.

Answer (score 1):

In your setup, the metal zinc is transformed into $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ ions plus electrons. The electrons can and will react with $\ce{H^+}$ ions in contact with the zinc plate, and this takes place when the circuit is open and when it is closed. It produces bubbles of $\ce{H2}$ gas. But this reaction is slow, because the reaction produces a positive charge ($\ce{Zn^{2+}}$) which repels the ions $\ce{H+}$, and prevent them from touching the zinc plate.

On the contrary, if the circuit is closed, the $\ce{H^+}$ ions are in contact of the copper plate without being repelled, and the reaction can proceed with a higher rate, as nothing prevents the electrons from reacting with the $\ce{H+}$ ions present in the solution. So Hydrogen is produced with a higher rate on the copper plate, even if it is far away from the zinc atoms which have produced them.